# Express route still returning item deleted from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have this route to delete a "garage" from the mongodb database and then grab some of the remaining garages. For some reason it is still returning the deleted garage and returning it, but if I check the database the delete was successful.

```
router.post('/garage/delete', requireLogin, async (req, res) => {
    let limit = 20;
    try {
        let list = req.body;
        list.map( async (item) => {
            const existingGarage = await Garage.find({_id: item._id});
            if (existingGarage) {
                await Garage.deleteOne({_id: item._id});
            } else {
                res.status(400).send("Garage not found");
            }
        })
        const allGarages = await Garage.find().limit( limit );
        console.log(allGarages);
        res.send(allGarages);
    } catch {
        res.status(400).send("Garage not found");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to await all the promises returned by the map function.

Promise.all awaits an array of promises and runs them in parallel. 
since you're passing an async function to the map function you will need to await all the promises returned by that async function
Other solution is to use a for of loop

```js
router.post('/garage/delete', requireLogin, async (req, res) => {
    let limit = 20;
    try {
        let list = req.body;
        await Promise.all(list.map( async (item) => {
            const existingGarage = await Garage.find({_id: item._id});
            if (existingGarage) {
                await Garage.deleteOne({_id: item._id});
            } else {
                res.status(400).send("Garage not found");
            }
        }))
        const allGarages = await Garage.find().limit( limit );
        console.log(allGarages);
        res.send(allGarages);
    } catch {
        res.status(400).send("Garage not found");
    }
})
```